# How photons get distributed in a system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, mean-free-path

Let's say I'm in a room, and there are plenty of things in my room like carpet,mirrors,glass and other stuff.And I see there are shadow regions and fully bright regions, and I want to know how photons are distributed in a system like this? Regions which are more bright have more photons and shadow regions have few photons.I want to calculate distribution of photons in this type of a system?

And what should I do to calculate photon distribution in this type of system,should I study Statistical mechanics or Quantum mechanics or Mean free path of a photon(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path) or anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Classical electrodynamics and optics are enough to study the macroscopic properties of light. One needs to consider photons for special situations, as in spectra, or very low illumination, where quantum mechanics has to be used. The classical electromagnetic field, reflection and refraction coefficients are enough for what you describe.

If you are interested in the complicated way that photons build up a classical wave have a look [here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html), and it is not simple.